# The \$I^2R\$ loss in transformer is eddy current loss or copper loss?

Tags: transformer

As the title say, this is what my text book say. I use Hughes Electrical Electronic Technology 10th edition

> The varying flux in the core induces e.m.f.s and hence currents in the core
>   material. These give rise to **\$I^2R\$ losses. These losses are called eddy-current
>   losses**

However then when I search through the internet

I found [this](http://www.electrical4u.com/hysteresis-eddy-current-iron-or-core-losses-and-copper-loss-in-transformer/) and it says

> Copper loss is I2R loss, in primary side it is \$I_1^2R_1\$ and in secondary side it is \$I_2^2R_2\$ loss,  where \$I_1\$ & \$I_2\$ are primary & secondary  current  of transformer and \$R_1\$ & \$R_2\$ are resistances of primary & secondary winding. As the both primary & secondary currents depend upon load of transformer, copper loss in transformer vary with load.

and

> **Hysteresis loss and eddy current  loss**, both depend upon magnetic properties of the materials used to construct the core of transformer and its design. So **these losses in transformer are fixed and do not depend upon the load current**

They are kinda contradict each other. So, what's the right definition for copper loss and eddy-current loss

Comment: Try to model the real transformer, find the component value of resistances and reactances in place, then measure and solve the relevant equations to find the total losses. May be you can use a common analysis s/w, but it is not so hard to do this by yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Copper loss' is I<sup>2</sup>R power loss in the windings due to current flowing through them. As this current increases with higher loading, so copper loss also increases as loading increases.

Eddy current loss is power loss in the magnetic core due to current induced into it (each lamination in the core is effectively a shorted turn, but the silicon steel has relatively high resistance which keeps the current down). The induced voltage - and thus current and power loss - doesn't change with loading because the magnetic flux in the core doesn't change. This is also I<sup>2</sup>R loss, but it is not copper loss.

To summarize, there are *two* places in the transformer where I<sup>2</sup>R losses occur - in the magnetic core and in the windings. However, only the windings have a power loss proportional to load current. That loss can rightly be called 'copper loss' because only the windings are made of copper.

Comment: I couldn't have said it better myself +1

Answer (score 0):

According to Hughes Electrical Electronic Technology 10th edition, when the magnetic flux changes in the core, it generates the current in the core material. And, it gives the power loss (I<sup>2</sup>R). These losses is called eddy current losses.
Form internet, it is given that loss in (I<sup>2</sup>R) means loss in power loss. And power loss depends upon the load. Thus, this definition is similar to your book.

For further detail you can visit here: -
http://www.mytech-info.com/2014/08/hysteresis-losses-eddy-current-losses.html

Comment: You are confusing copper losses and eddy current losses. Generally, in transformers, I2R loss is copper loss.